# Django, assigning a composite value to one field depending upon values entered in other fields in same model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am new to django. What I am currently trying to do is set a value which is a primary key and non-editable automatically generated depending upon the values entered in the same model to some other fields. Here is an example:

```
   class Student(models.Model):
      student_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=true)
      name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      class  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      roll_no  = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

So, what I am trying to achieve is if someone enters following information :

```
name = Haris
class = 8th
roll_no = 104011
```

The automatically generated primary key that would be non-editable for field "student_id" would be:

```
student_id = Haris_8th_104011
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? Hope my example made the query clear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way overriding save method. Note that class variable clashesh with original builtin class name please migrate once as i changed the variable name

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    classes = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    roll_no = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.student_id = f'{self.name}_{self.classes}_{self.roll_no}'
        super(Student,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Okay right, but how do I view it in front end? I mean in my app I have name, classes and roll_no as dropdowns from which I am selecting the options and I want to get the student_id updated as per options selected before submitting the form. Can you throw a light on that as well please?

Comment: It will be autosave or updated when you call save method no need to handle that

Comment: Let me try, if that's the case i will upvote your answer

Comment: Did it worked ?

Comment: Thanks Sir it's working. I have upvoted and accepted the answer. Just one more thing, if I want to view the updated student_id value for that instance as well in the form before submitting it, how should I go about it?

Comment: Just get instance of your class
i.e student = Student.objects get(pk=studentid) and you can do student.studentid hope you got idea you need instance of your model

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, you saved the day.

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Comment: Sir I have another question that is not answered yet. If you could provide a feedback, I would be glad.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70694650/django-how-to-add-zoom-in-zoom-out-functionality-into-preview-function-in-javas

Comment: I am sorry i dont know js :(

Comment: No worries man. Can you kindly provide more detail about the instance methodology you mentioned in this question though?

Comment: while update you need primary key basically pk and from that pk you can get instance i.e
student=Student.objects,get(pk=id)
now you can print student id as  (student.student_id)

Comment: And this instance would go into the save function you mentioned above or we are to define a new function? Pardon my basic queries as I am fairly beginner to the developer cycle.

Comment: just use student.save()  no need any other thing becasuse student is model instance and save is instance method of class

Comment: Yes right, thanks a lot man!